# Eclipse Error (FNAF Minigame Simulation)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one last error for the FNAF mini-game simulation.  It's something about an illegal argument?

Now, here is my error :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at Minigame.<init>(Minigame.java:40)
    at Minigame.main(Minigame.java:140)`

...And here is my code (one class only) :

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Minigame extends JPanel
{   
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

GameEvents gameEvents = new GameEvents();
Timer gameTimer = new Timer(1, gameEvents);
int i = 0; 
int horizontalposition = 500;
int verticalposition = 500;

BufferedImage Picture;
BufferedImage Picture2;
BufferedImage Picture3;
BufferedImage Picture4;
BufferedImage Picture5;
BufferedImage Picture6; 

//Don't forget to declare your variables!


Minigame() {
    gameTimer.start();
    this.addKeyListener(gameEvents);

    try 
    {

        System.out.println("Processing...");

        Picture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Child.gif"));
        Picture2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Static_Background.jpg"));
        Picture3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Purple_Person.png"));
        Picture4 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Cake_Child_Idle.png"));
        Picture5 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Freddy2.gif"));
        Picture6 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Freddy.gif"));
        //How do you use gifs?
        //The format for this is Picture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("NameOfFile.typeoffile"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Pictures failed to load");
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    ///g.drawImage(Picture, horizontalposition, verticalposition, 100, 150, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture2, 0, 0, 1500, 1700, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture, 200, 10, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture, 200, 100, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture, 200, 200, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture, 200, 300, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture, 200, 400, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture, 200, 500, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture3, 1100, 50, 100, 150, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture4, 1000, 100, 70, 100, null);
    g.drawImage(Picture6, horizontalposition, verticalposition, 100, 150, null);

}

public class GameEvents implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) //stuff inside here happens when a key is pressed
    {
        if(key.getKeyChar()=='d')
        {
            horizontalposition=horizontalposition+50;
        }
        if(key.getKeyChar()=='s')
        {
            verticalposition=verticalposition+50;
        }
        if(key.getKeyChar()=='w')
        {
            verticalposition=verticalposition-50;
        }
        if(key.getKeyChar()=='a')
        {
            horizontalposition=horizontalposition-50;
        }

        if(horizontalposition<200)
        {
            horizontalposition=200;
        }
        if(horizontalposition>900)
        {
            horizontalposition=900;
        }

        if(verticalposition<-50)
        {
            verticalposition=-50;
        }
        if(verticalposition>525)
        {
            verticalposition=525;
        }

        System.out.println(key.getKeyChar());
        System.out.println('d');
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Java Graphics Example Project");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Minigame p = new Minigame();
    f.setSize(1500,700);
    System.out.println("Processer Complete.");
    f.add(p);
    System.out.println("IT'S ME.");
    f.setVisible(true);
    p.requestFocusInWindow();

    }

}
```

Anyways, I am very new to Eclipse, so please be specific. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One thing, can you please highlight line 140

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing since this issue is over 7 years old you've probably figured this out by now.

You might need to just add the images to your eclipse classpath.  You can do it by right clicking the folder the images are stored in and right click the folder mouse over build path and just click "add to build path".